# Transforming a symmetric matrix into pentadiagonal form

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a symmetric matrix $A$, which has complex values in the diagonal, but whose all other entries are real, I am interested in finding an orthonormal transformation $Q$ such that $Q^tAQ$ is a [pentadiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadiagonal_matrix) whose entries outside of the main diagonal are real. So far, I have not even been able to prove if it's possible to always find such a transformation. Is there maybe any constructive numerical algortihm to attain this?

Comment: what happens with 6 by 6 matrix?

Comment: I really don't know. What happens? Anyway, in the problem I am concerned with the matrices are much larger.

Comment: I imagine matrix $Q$ needs to have real coefficients ?